# Animating Text inside Unslider container

Tags: jquery, unslider

I was trying call a function that would fade in header texts one after another inside the unslider container.
The best way would be to probably call a function after each slide transition is complete.

But I can't seem to get the function called using the 'complete' option in Unslider.

Even the following code is not working for me:

```
 $('.banner').unslider({
    complete: function() {
       alert("Test");
     }
 });
```

The slider is working fine, but the function to animate the header text is not triggered.

I have setup the HTML as instructed in the [Unslider](http://unslider.com/) website

```
   <div class="banner">
     <ul>
         <li style="background-image: url('image1.jpg')">
               <h1> Heading 1 </h1>
               <h2> Heading 2 </h1>
         </li>
         <li style="background-image: url('image2.jpg')">
               <h1> Heading 1 </h1>
               <h2> Heading 2 </h1>
         </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

I really don't understand what I am doing wrong, would appreciate if someone could show me the way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any error thrown? Are you using an onload method to call your script? For me it does work : http://jsfiddle.net/moumvyex/

Comment: @Kaiido

Its very strange, but this is what I found out.

The callbacks using 'complete' option works when I use the unslider.js
file from the official website.

I wanted a fade effect, not a slide effect, so I used a [fork](https://github.com/jeremymlane/unslider) of the original.

The 'complete' option is not working for me in this forked one.

Comment: can you give the sources of this fork?

Comment: Here you go!

[Link to Source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jeremymlane/unslider/master/src/unslider.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the `complete` event hasn't been integrated in this new fork.
Just add this line to your .js file l190 to gain the event back while using `fade : true`

```
    ul.find("li").eq(index).fadeIn(speed);
    $.isFunction(o.complete) && !callback && o.complete(el, target);//add this line
 } else {
```

Comment: I tried to upvote, but I don't have enough reputation to do so. 
Sorry about that!